# Ancient .IDE project having errors in Visual Studio 2015 system files

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I'm resurrecting an ancient project, one developed when the Visual Studio project type was "IDE". I've got everything building, except for cmath errors like:

'acoshl': ambiguous call to overloaded function

in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath.

I have no references to cmath or math.h in my code, and nothing tells me why there is a conflict with functions never referenced. Obviously,  I don't want to edit system files. :)

Comment: You appear to be mixing standard library implementations. Don't do that.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio was the project originally built in?